# ActiveRecord has_many relationships forget changes to children?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an instance of type A that has_many Bs. When the `A.foo = value` method gets called, I actually want to write a method that delegates to that foo= call the first of the A's Bs.

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bs, autosave: true

  def foo
    bs.first.foo
  end
  def foo=(val)
    bs.first.foo = val
  end
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to A
end


rails generate model A 
rails generate model B a:references foo:string


2.3.0 :001 > a = A.create!
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "as" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2016-10-08 18:03:18.255107"], ["updated_at", "2016-10-08 18:03:18.255107"]]
   (7.8ms)  commit transaction
 => #<A id: 1, created_at: "2016-10-08 18:03:18", updated_at: "2016-10-08 18:03:18">
```

Create an A and call it `a`.

```
2.3.0 :002 > b = B.create!(a: a, foo: "initial")
   (0.4ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "bs" ("a_id", "foo", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["a_id", 1], ["foo", "initial"], ["created_at", "2016-10-08 18:03:40.658035"], ["updated_at", "2016-10-08 18:03:40.658035"]]
   (8.3ms)  commit transaction
 => #<B id: 1, a_id: 1, foo: "initial", created_at: "2016-10-08 18:03:40", updated_at: "2016-10-08 18:03:40">
```

Create a B and call it `b`. Make it a child of A. Set it's foo property to "initial".

```
2.3.0 :003 > a.reload.foo
  A Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "as".* FROM "as" WHERE "as"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  B Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "bs".* FROM "bs" WHERE "bs"."a_id" = ?  ORDER BY "bs"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["a_id", 1]]
 => "initial"
```

Check that `a` sees it's new child's `foo`: yes. As expected.

```
2.3.0 :004 > a.foo = "set"
  B Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "bs".* FROM "bs" WHERE "bs"."a_id" = ?  ORDER BY "bs"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["a_id", 1]]
 => "set" 
2.3.0 :005 > a.foo
  B Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "bs".* FROM "bs" WHERE "bs"."a_id" = ?  ORDER BY "bs"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["a_id", 1]]
 => "initial"
```

Whaaat? I just called `a.foo = "set"`. Now when I call `a.foo` again to read the value back, I get `"initial"`? That's not the way it works for `has_one` relationships. Why is ActiveRecord reloading from the DB every time, instead of caching it's queries?

Ultimately, my intention is to call `a.save!`, and have it autosave down to the b. But that's not possible if the relationship gets amnesia about every pending change. What's going on here?!

Comment: Rails does not cache queries when you run the commands in the console.

Comment: Good to know. But it according to my understanding, AR Model should be caching the first query anyway: a.bs should be a lazily evaluated query to the DB, that is fetched on first access, and then sticks around in array form until save! is called on it's parent. Or so I thought.

Comment: Has_one and belongs_to associations cache their results:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference:
4.1.1.1 and 4.2.1.1
"If the associated object has already been retrieved from the database for this object, the cached version will be returned."

The documentation is SILENT on this caching for the collection method in 4.3.1.1. It just doesn't do it. It queries each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a `has_one` relationship between A and B and delegate :foo to the `has_one` association.

```
class A
  has_many :bs
  has_one :first_b, -> { first },
    class_name: 'B'
  delegate :foo, to: :first_b
end
```

To avoid the query for B you can use [`.joins`, `includes` or `eager_load`](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html).

Comment: hmmm, when I run this, I get

   "NoMethodError: undefined method `except' for #<B:0x000000037915f0>"

It's not coming from the delegate call, so it must be coming from the has_one?

Comment: What happens if you run `a.first_b`?

Comment: You did remember to set it up to inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base` or `ApplicationModel` (rails 5)?

Comment: a.first_b returns the same 'undefined method: except' error as above.

I did subclass ActiveRecord::Base. (I briefly tried in rails 5.0.0.1, and got the same error, but I didn't think to change the superclass to ApplicationModel)

Comment: I can't really tell anything without a stack trace. However I'm guessing that this is most likely a X & Y problem. Whatever the real goal is there is probably a better way to do it.

Comment: The problem seems to be the call to 'first'. That stabby lambda needs to return a relation.

Comment: X&Y:

We're modelling the hiring of people in our database. A pairing of a person and a company is called a "hire". Then the person may have one or more positions within the company. 

We deal with a common pattern of positions, where first people have the position of "apprentice", and then they go on to get a "first full time" position.  Among the sea of positions, we need to be able to update the values for the apprenticeship position and the first full time position.

Comment: [cont'd]


Rather than using an order-based list, I'm currently pretty keen to label the positions with "apprentice", "full time", or nil. Then use your `where has_one, -> { ...}, class name 'B'` approach to get caching. 

Thank you for this idea!! :D